Spark fails at dropDuplicates() due to multiple ExecutorLostFailure
I have 479 parquet files (each approx. 120 MB, totaling a little over 2 billion records) stored on HDFS and I was trying to determine the best Spark configuration for this dataset, but I am unable to complete the dropDuplicates() operation. My HDFS configuration is:
NameNode: 4 core/24 GB RAM;
3 DataNode: 8 core/24 GB RAM
The PySpark code I tried to execute is:
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

configuration = {
    "spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields": 100,
    "spark.executor.cores": 7,
    "spark.executor.memory": "21g",
    "spark.executor.instances": 3,
}
config = SparkConf().setAll(configuration.items())
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.master("spark://192.168.1.1:7077")
    .config(conf=config)
    .appName("my_app")
    .getOrCreate()
)
df = spark.read.parquet(f"{directory}/*.parquet").dropDuplicates()
df.count()

In my most recent run, the application ran for over two hours and there were several blocks of warning that look like this:
24/12/12 16:37:23 WARN HeartbeatReceiver: Removing executor 1 with no recent heartbeats: 140008 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms

24/12/12 16:37:23 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 1 on 192.168.1.2: Executor heartbeat timed out after 140008 ms

24/12/12 16:37:23 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 13.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 6752) (192.168.1.2 executor 1): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 140008 ms

24/12/12 16:37:23 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 6743) (192.168.1.2 executor 1): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 140008 ms

24/12/12 16:37:23 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 34.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 6773) (192.168.1.2 executor 1): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 140008 ms

24/12/12 16:37:23 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 6740) (192.168.1.2 executor 1): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 140008 ms

24/12/12 16:37:23 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 36.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 6775) (192.168.1.2 executor 1): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 140008 ms

24/12/12 16:37:23 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 32.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 6771) (192.168.1.2 executor 1): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 140008 ms

24/12/12 16:37:23 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 38.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 6777) (192.168.1.2 executor 1): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 140008 ms

24/12/12 16:37:35 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /192.168.1.2:53018

java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer

    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)

    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)

    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)

    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)

    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)

    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:259)

    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)

    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)

    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)

    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)

    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)

    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)

    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)

    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)

    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)

    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

The final error I received was:
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40.count.

: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 21 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 21.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 6918) (192.168.1.2 executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 147123 ms

Driver stacktrace:

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2785)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)

    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)

    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)

    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)

    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2984)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2923)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2912)

    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)

Am I doing something wrong in my configuration? I was under the impression that Spark should continue to chug through the data, and even if there are resource constraints, it will finish the job. Obviously, I was wrong. But how can I get this job to complete?

Consider doing
df.agg(f.countDistinct("primary_key1", "primary_key2", ... "primary_keyn")).show()
df.dropDuplicates("primary_key1", "primary_key2", ... "primary_keyn").count().show() is an un-optimised way to achieve the same.
If you don't know the primary columns, consider doing a
df.agg(f.countDistinct("*")).show()
My best guess to what is happening is that there are too many keys (hashes) to be created. Behind the scene, spark is trying to create hash of the column values combinations. That is how it does a dropDuplicates()
